# JSON deserialization, get properties name not value

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

First of all, this question may have been asked before, but I couldn't find an answer due to poor wording I guess.

I get a weirdly formatted JSON string back from a `WebService` call

```
{
    "id":5000174774,
    "name":"company_name",
    "choices":
    {
        "Farmway":
        {
            "Head Office (BSU)":[],
            "Alnwick":[],
            "Bury St Edmunds":[]
        },
        "Tate":
        {
            "Head Office":[],
            "Tate Britain Entrance":[]
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the classes I'd like to use for deserialization

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("choices")]
    public Company[] Companies{ get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public string[] Shops { get; set; }
}
```

I've never seen a JSON formatted like that, and I have no idea how to get the properties name instead of values. `"choices"` is not an `array` but an `object`, but I can't know its properties beforehand. I just want to get all companies and their shops.

I hope it makes some kind of sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your deserializer, but usually a good candidate is a `Dictionary`:

```
[JsonProperty("choices")]
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<OfSomething>> Companies { get; set; }
```

So, your first key is a string, with the name of the company, and the value is another dictionary, linking company BU's to list/arrays of I-don't-know-what.

If you then need to elaborate this structure into something else, you can process it with a bit of Linq.